# Identifying non-trivial functional dependencies in database tables

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Which non-trivial functional dependencies can be discovered in this table?
Are there any systematic approaches that can be used to do so?

```
|  first_name  |  surname  |  student_id  |  program_code  |  name_of_study  |
```

Comment: You should add more context information that is clearly needed to derive functional dependencies. What is program code? Is this a table that manages submitted source code? With stud_id, do you mean student id or study id?

Comment: Then let's assume that this is the table for a source code submission system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at database normalization, especially at following concepts

- [1. normal form (1NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)
- [2. normal form (2NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)
- [3. normal form (3NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)
- [Boyce–Codd normal form (BCNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form).

It's been a while for me, but here we go:

`first_name`, `surname` can be derived by `student_id` so we put them in an own table named students, `student_id` is the **foreign key**, that's why it's marked with an asterisk.

```
------------students---------------
| *student_id* | first_name| surname |
```

The mapping from student to their subject should be placed in a different table

```
-----------subjects-----------
| *student_id* | name_of_study  |
```

and the last table contains the code submissions

```
-----------submissions-------
| *student_id* | program_code |
```

Nevertheless, it's been I while since I had my database lecture, so I'd
recommend you to read through the links I provided.

The columns in the table are (or should be if I did it right),
functionally dependent from the foreign key.